# Weird strings when reading the GPS data from the receiver

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpsd

I tried to read the GPS data from the receiver. I got strange strings as a result. Where is the problem?

```
import serial

port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"    # Raspberry Pi 3

def parseGPS(data):
        print(data)
        #...

ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 0.5)
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    parseGPS(data)
```

result
[image]

Comment: _"Strange strings?"_ NMEA 0183?

Comment: Check your baud rate

Comment: Thanks guys, you both were right. This is NMEA 0183. I set the baud rate to 4800 and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the wrong baud rate. Next example works problem-free:

```
import serial

port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"  # Raspberry Pi 3

def parseGPS(data):
   print(data)
   # ...

ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=4800, timeout=0.5)
while True:
   data = ser.readline()
   parseGPS(data)
```